# unittest Mock - patch return value

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.4, python-unittest

I think I misunderstand how to use mocks for changing a function return value. Here is my test :

```
from path.to import programme_finder
@patch('path.to.programme_finder._calc_update_interval')
def test_refresh_interval(self,method_mock):
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    dd = datetime.timedelta(millisecond=20)
    earlier_date = today - dd
    #The normal function returns a 5 day interval.
    # For tests I want it down to 20ms
    method_mock.return_value = earlier_date
    #Here I would expect a date object, instead I get MagicMock
    print("Calc returns %s " % programme_finder._calc_update_interval)
    # rest of the test irrelevant 
    self.fail("need to time responce time")
```

What am I doing wrong ? How do I get the `programme_finder._calc_update_interval` to return my patched `datetime`?

Tried

```
assert programme_finder._calc_update_interval == earlier_date
```

as well and it fails.

```
#programme_finder.py
def _calc_update_interval():
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    # The days we want to subtract for today.
    update_interval = current_app.config.get("RESOURCE_UPDATE_INTERVAL")
    dd = datetime.timedelta(days=update_interval)
    # Find which date it was x days ago 
    earlier_date = today - dd
    return earlier_date
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like you're not calling the function -- you're referencing it by name, so you get back the mocked function instead of your mock return value.

```
print("Calc returns %s " % programme_finder._calc_update_interval )
                                                                 ^reference
```

Should be

```
print("Calc returns %s " % programme_finder._calc_update_interval() )
                                                                 ^^call
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that `_calc_update_interval` is a property (I'm guessing created with the `@property` decorator) and not a method. The easiest approach is to simply use the `PropertyMock` class provided with mock (Documented [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.PropertyMock)):

```
@patch('path.to.programme_finder._calc_update_interval', new_callable=PropertyMock):
def test_refresh_interval(self,method_mock):
    #...
```

Comment: No _calc_update_interval is a function. Ill add it to the question.